# Java PSI WCF implementation

Tags: java, wcf, ms-project

I have a project server instance that Id like to connect to in java. I'm new to the technology and not really sure how to do this.

I know I'm supposed to used WCF.

Essentially , Id like to read the number of projects on the MSP instance and print them out as a string.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Appreciate any reference material too.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there are two options to do that:

1. Read from Database. JDBC driver for MS SQL will help you with that
2. Write intermediate server using .NET. PSI uses DataSets to communicate between client and server. There is no implementation of the DataSets for Java.

Comment: Thanks for the Ideas Melan, both interesting. Could you expand a little in writing an intermediate server please? I dont understand what that is. Thanks for your support.

Comment: Kind of proxy server which will take .NET DataSets and convert them into a Java understandable structures e.g. to Google ProtoBuf, and do reverse conversion when something should be submitted to the PSI